# Is it acceptable to repeat variables, when listing variables for certain objects?

Tags: coding-style, conventions

Here's an example case:

```
public list getPizzaIngredients(pizzaName)
{
    if pizzaName = HAWAIIAN
       return [
              CHEESE,
              TOMATO SAUCE,
              PINEAPPLE, 
              HAM];
    if pizzaName = ITALIAN
       return [
               CHEESE,
               TOMATO SAUCE,
               PEPPERONI,
               OLIVES]; 

    if pizzaName = MEATLOVERS
       return [
               CHEESE,
               TOMATO SAUCE,
               PEPPERONI,
               BACON,
               SAUSAGE,
               OLIVES]; 

    return null;  
}
```

Here we are repeating ingredients in each list. An alternative way to do is:

```
public list getPizzaIngrediants(pizzaName)
{
    ing = [];
    ing.add(CHEESE) 
    ing.add(TOMATO SAUCE); 
    if pizzaName in (HAWAIIAN)            ing.add(PINEAPPLE);
    if pizzaName in (HAWAIIAN)            ing.add(HAM);  
    if pizzaName in (ITALIAN, MEATLOVERS) ing.add(PEPPERONI);
    if pizzaName in (ITALIAN, MEATLOVERS) ing.add(OLIVES);
    if pizzaName in (MEATLOVERS)          ing.add(BACON);   
    if pizzaName in (MEATLOVERS)          ing.add(SAUSAGE); 

return ing;
```

or we could make it more concise:

```
public list getPizzaIngrediants(pizzaName)
{
    ing = []; 
    ing.add(CHEESE,TOMATO SAUCE) 
    if pizzaName in (HAWAIIAN)            ing.add(PINEAPPLE, HAM);
    if pizzaName in (ITALIAN, MEATLOVERS) ing.add(PEPPERONI, OLIVES);
    if pizzaName in (MEATLOVERS)          ing.add(BACON, SAUSAGE);   

return ing;
```

Now personally - although the first example is wordier and involves repeating the variables, it's far more readable and easier to modify than the other two solutions.

Is there a convention around this kind of programming style/issue?

Comment: Because this question is primarily opinion based, there is not one answer to this question and should therefore be closed.

Comment: I disagree - this is not a question that can be answered only via opinion.  The question is if there is a convention around such standard programming tasks.  I would say that while there is no standard, per say, you'll find that how you implement such a solution is determined quite often by your environment.  In a workplace you may have standards that dictate efficiency or dictate readability; it is to the situation you are in, I think.  However, I think that in the above case the "right way" to handle it is more about whether you're looking for efficiency, readability, or something in between

Answer (score 2):

If you just have constants HAWAIIAN ITALIAN MEATLOVERS, put them in an enum, preferably in the first format - nice and readable.

If pizza and toppings are, as is very likely, going to be real concepts with the potential for future *change* (VEGGIE?!? kinds of cheese?), all of these will break, in the sense that there is no one change to make to your code. All it takes is a second property of pizza besides ingredients (price()? tasty()?) and for each new pizza you must write code in multiple places. Then you should use a proper object oriented design, a class hierarchy with subclasses of abstracts Pizza and Ingredients.

There is a lengthy pizza store example covering very similar ground in the Factory chapter of Head First Design Patterns.